# LyX -- Title, Abstract, Keywords Missing When Using Elsevier Class in View

Tags: formatting, tex, lyx

I'm pretty new to using LyX, but have looked around this forum, as well as others and haven't found anyone else who has encountered this problem.

The issue is that, when I click on the 'eyes' to preview my document in .pdf form, there are the two numbered sections with the corresponding body text, but my title, abstract, and keywords, as well as the 'new page' formatting, are all missing; the two sections are at the top of the page as though they had never been included.

Some pertinent information:

1. LyX has recently been installed (last couple of weeks)
2. I'm running OSX 10.9.5
3. My version of LyX is 2.1.3
4. I'm using the Elsevier document class

The following is the TeX source:

```
       % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
 %% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
 \documentclass[letterpaper,english]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

 \makeatletter

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
 \pdfpageheight\paperheight
 \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


 \makeatother

 \usepackage{babel}
  \begin{document}

  \title{ This is where my title is }


 \author{My name}
 \begin{abstract}
 Abstract: This is my abstarct.\end{abstract}
 \begin{keyword}
 Keywords: Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword 3
 \end{keyword}
 \newpage{}


 \section{Introduction}

  My intro text

 \section{Literature Review}

 My body text
 \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and help out!

-Mike

Edit1: After adding `\begin{frontmatter}{}` and `\end{frontmatter}{}` before the title and after the keywords, things seem to be working (ie. the title, keywords, abstract and authors are all working) -- does the Elsevier document class force this to be used when denoting these items?

Answer (score 2):

as suggested in the link below:
In the pulldown menu where you set your title text to be the Title, there's entries for BeginFrontmatter and EndFrontmatter. You need to put the first before your title and the second after your keywords.
In the pulldown menu where you set your title text to be the Title, there's entries for BeginFrontmatter and EndFrontmatter. You need to put the first before your title and the second after your keywords.
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=24933