# Lyx missing abstract in output for sage journal article

Tags: layout, latex, lyx

I've successfully added a document class called "article (sagej)" into Lyx using the .cls file found at

https://uk.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_0.zip

However, I have two issues in using it. First, in the layout drop-down menu containing layout options (Standard, Section, Section*, Abstract, etc.) there is no "Keywords".

Second, whether or not I use Tex code right after the Abstract (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> --> `\keywords{key1, key2}`), there are no output of the abstract and/or key words in the pdf file.

I use Lyx 2.1.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 with TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian).

The following is an example.

[Here is what it looks like in Lyx editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKsCZ.png)

The Lyx-generated tex:

```
\batchmode
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/home/wjc/MyPaper/Calibration//}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[english,Afour, times]{sagej}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\lyxaddress}[1]{
\par {\raggedright #1
\vspace{1.4em}
\noindent\par}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{This is a title}


\author{Jerry Author Smith}

\maketitle

\lyxaddress{From: Somewhere on earth}
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\textbf{\textbf{\keywords{Key1, Key2}}}


\section{Introduction}

Introduction of the topic


\section{Methods}

Methods and materials
\end{document}
```

I can't post two pictures. But the abstract and key words don't show in the PDF file. All other information are shown: title, author, address, main text.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: This question is probably closely related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476394/lyx-title-abstract-keywords-missing-when-using-elsevier-class-in-view?rq=1). It could be a fundamental Lyx problem?

Comment: Here is the output PDF. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OvAu5.png